# LinQ adding unwanted (@__term_0 LIKE N'') to SQL queries

Tags: linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core, linqkit

I have an `IQueryable` extension in my `User` model where I'm using [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) :

```
public static IQueryable<User> ApplyFilterTerms(this IQueryable<User> query, string search)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(search)) 
        return query;

    var searchTerms = search.Split(' ').Where(x => x.Length > 0).ToArray();

    if (!searchTerms.Any()) 
        return query;

    var termsPredicate = searchTerms.Aggregate(
        LinqExtensions.True<User>(),
        (current, term) => current.And(
            LinqExtensions.False<User>()
                .Or(x => x.FirstName.Contains(term))
                .Or(x => x.LastName.Contains(term))
                .Or(x => x.UserName.Contains(term))
        ));

    return query.Where(termsPredicate);
}
```

When executing this db query, LinQ translates it into something in this pattern:

```
DECLARE @__term_0 AS VARCHAR(100) = 'jonh'

SELECT [u].[UserId], [u].[FirstName], [u].[LastName], [u].[UserName]
FROM [Users] AS [u]
WHERE (((@__term_0 LIKE N'') OR (CHARINDEX(@__term_0, [u].[FirstName]) > 0))
   OR ((@__term_0 LIKE N'') OR (CHARINDEX(@__term_0, [u].[LastName]) > 0)))
   OR ((@__term_0 LIKE N'') OR (CHARINDEX(@__term_0, [u].[UserName]) > 0))
ORDER BY [u].[FirstName], [u].[LastName]
```

Would there be a way to remove this apparently useless `(@__term_0 LIKE N'')` that linq adds to the query?

Comment: Which EF Core version and which Data Provider? I'll check source code.

Comment: I think this isn't a problem with LinqKit but with EF translate

Comment: My project isn't using LinqKit, and it's having the same issue.